# Getting date value from django queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a Models like below

```
class Member(models.Model):
    memberid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    memberdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    mname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    mobile1 = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    dob = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I am fetching data to display in the html template. For the view below is the code

```
def updateMemberView(request, id):
    searchmem= id
    member = Member.objects.filter(memberid=searchmem).values()
    print(member[0])
    return render(request, 'Member/member_update_form.html', {"member": member})
```

Now in print(member[0]) I am getting

```
{'memberid': 13, 'memberdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 11, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'fname': 'Akash', 'mname': 'chimanbhai', 'lname': 'khatri', 'mobile1': '', 'email': 'kashkhatri@yahoo.com', 'dob': datetime.datetime(2020, 4,    3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

But when I try to print the value of dob in template using member.0.dob it gives me error. 
Also when I try to execute command

```
print(member[0].dob)
```

this also give me error 
'dict' object has no attribute 'dob'

So How could I get the dob value in view and also in template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *dictionary*. You access the value corresponding to a key in a dictionary by *subscripting*:

```
print(member[0]['dob'])
```

That being said, using [**`.values(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) should be used scarcely, especially since you erase the logical layer of the model. For example foreign keys are no longer retrieved lazily, you only have the value of the primary key.

You can simply pass the model object to the template:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def update_member_view(request, id):
    member = get_object_or_404(Member, memberid=id)
    return render(request, 'Member/member_update_form.html', {'member': member})
```

Some common mistakes:

1. functions are normally written in `slug_case`, not in `PerlCase`, or `camelCase`;
2. it is better to use `get_object_or_404` to return a HTTP 404 exception if the object can not be found; and
3. as said before, pass the `Member` object itself, that way you can add extra methods to the model that you can use in the tempate.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed the code as per above and it is also easy to write.